# Obtain a rank $2$ set of columns from a union of two sets of columns, each of rank $3$

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, linear-transformations

let $$e_1=\left[\begin{matrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ -1
\end{matrix}\right], e_2=\left[\begin{matrix}
2 \\ 1 \\ -1
\end{matrix}\right], e_3=\left[\begin{matrix}
-2 \\ 1 \\ 4
\end{matrix}\right].$$ be a basis set for $\mathbf R^3$. Obtain $$c_1 = 2e_1 + (-10) e_2 = \left[\begin{matrix}
-18 \\ -10 \\ 8
\end{matrix}\right], c_2 = (-7)e_2 + 9 e_3 = \left[\begin{matrix}
-32 \\ 2 \\ 43
\end{matrix}\right].$$ Let $$M_1 = [e_1,e_2,e_3,c_1,c_2].$$

Similarly,
let $$v_1=\left[\begin{matrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 0 
\end{matrix}\right], v_2=\left[\begin{matrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{matrix}\right], v_3=\left[\begin{matrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{matrix}\right].$$ be another basis set for $\mathbf R^3$. Obtain $$d_1 = (-5)v_1 + (6) v_3 = \left[\begin{matrix}
1 \\ -5 \\ 6
\end{matrix}\right], d_2 = 11 v_2 + (-3) v_3 = \left[\begin{matrix}
-3 \\ 11 \\ 8
\end{matrix}\right].$$ Let $$M_2 = [v_1,v_2,v_3,d_1,d_2].$$

In the set of rank $3$ columns $$M =[M_1, M_2]=[e_1,e_2,e_3,c_1,c_2,v_1,v_2,v_3,d_1,d_2],$$ what columns are needed to be deleted in $M$ to obtain a set of columns  of rank $2$.

Is there a general solution to problems of this type.

Comment: They all have to lie in the same plane for it to be a rank 2 set. So just take the cross productof two vectors, dot it with the rest and see which ones don't go to zero.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan.  Thanks. if i want to do it for dimension $k$, and obtain a set of columns of dimension $k-1$, then how do i do it. I want to do it over finite fields. Is there any notes/theory related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the rank to be $2$, all the vectors must be in the same plane, so you start by choosing 2 vectors, find their cross product (it will be a vector perpendicular to the plane they are in, so now you have to do the scalar product of this new vector (say $\vec z$) with all the others and choose those that give you a zero answer. (Because if the answer of the dot product iz zero, then the vectors are perpendicular, and any vector perpendicular to $\vec z$ will lie in your plane, so you'll gaurantee a rank of $2$) .

Comment: Thanks. if i want to do it for dimension $k$, and obtain a set of columns of dimension $k-1$, then how do i do it. I want to do it over finite fields. Is there any notes/theory related to this.